# Where can I place addslashes coding that will allow "/',. (punctuation) to show up on the webpage

Tags: php, mysql

Where can I place the addslashes or magicquotes coding that will allow punctuation to show up when users submit data to the website for the name and city fields?

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {   
$name=$_POST["element_1"];
$xxx=$_POST["element_2_1"];
$xxxxx=$_POST["element_2_2"];
$xxxxx=$_POST["element_2_3"];
$xxxxx=$_POST["element_3_1"];
$xxxxxd=$_POST["element_3_2"];
$xxxxxx=$_POST["element_3_3"];
$xxxxx=$_POST["element_4_1"];
$xxxxx=$_POST["element_4_2"];
$city=$_POST["element_4_3"];
$xxx=$_POST["element_4_4"];
$xxp=$_POST["element_4_5"];
$desc=$_POST["element_5"];
//$file=$_FILES['element_6'];
$link=$_POST["element_7"];
$stdate=$stdatemm."-".$stdatedd."-".$stdateyy;
$endate=$endatemm."-".$endatedd."-".$endateyy;
$user=$_POST["postuser"];
```

Comment: use PDO to save your data to mysql - PDO does escaping for you.

Comment: If you instead want to go the cumbersome route, add [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) around all string variables (instead of addslashes). See [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174) for the easier approach.

Comment: @user2512412: I assumed you wanted to save the user input to database, right? Here's a website for PDO: http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers and remember, google is your friend ;-)

Comment: As a pro tip: If you are currently learning from documentation or a tutorial which instructs you to use `addslashes()` or magic_quotes_gpc, _stop using it right now_ and find an up to date reference.  Start with the SQL injection post linked by @mario.  Methods like `addslashes()` fell out of favor many many years ago, and magic_quotes_gpc was deprecated 4+ years ago.

Comment: And don't use dates in MM-DD-YY format.  MySQL wants them in YYYY-MM-DD format.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the user-submitted content while saving it to the database.

```
// Your var with `"/'` chars
$name=$_POST["element_1"];

// Escape it for database storage
$name_escaped = mysql_real_escape_string($name);

// Use the escaped version in your query
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (column) VALUES ('" . $name_escaped . "')");
```

Note: The [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) function must be called after you have init the MySQL connection, but before you execute your MySQL query.

**Note: This way of executing MySQL queries is deprecated as of PHP 5.5, therefore you should use the [`Mysqli`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.statements.php) or [`PDO`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) methods.**

In any case, when retrieving the content from the database it shouldn't be escaped, therefor if you want to display it on an HTML page make sure to use [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) so chars like "`<`" don't break the HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div>
        <?php echo htmlspecialchars($name_fromDB); ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```